# XSLT: Sort by multiple items

Tags: xslt, xerces

I have XML data such as:

```
<feed>
  <entry>
    <id>4</id>
    <updated>2011-01-18T16:55:54Z</updated>
    <title>title2</title>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <id>3</id>
    <updated>2011-01-18T16:55:54Z</updated>
    <title>title1</title>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <id>2</id>
    <updated>2011-01-18T16:55:54Z</updated>
    <title>title1</title>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <id>1</id>
    <updated>2011-01-18T16:55:54Z</updated>
    <title>title</title>
  </entry>
</feed>
```

And I need the outcome to result like:

```
<feed>
  <entry>
    <id>1</id>
    <updated>2011-01-18T16:55:54Z</updated>
    <title>title</title>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <id>2</id>
    <updated>2011-01-18T16:55:54Z</updated>
    <title>title1</title>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <id>3</id>
    <updated>2011-01-18T16:55:54Z</updated>
    <title>title1</title>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <id>4</id>
    <updated>2011-01-18T16:55:54Z</updated>
    <title>title2</title>
  </entry>
</feed>
```

Basically I need the XSLT to sort on the title, then the ID. I have made an XSLT but the shorter times come out last (using Xerces):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
<xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />

 <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" />
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="atom:feed">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="*" />
   <xsl:for-each select="atom:entry">
    <xsl:sort select="string-length(atom:title)" order="descending" />
    <xsl:sort select="atom:title" data-type="text" order="ascending" />
    <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
   </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="atom:feed/atom:entry"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: If by "shorter items" you mean `entry/title` with a smaller `string-length()`, then the requirement to sort on this length is conflicting with the recuirement to sort on `entry/title` in alphabetical order. For example how do you want to sort two entries with titles with string values "Zoo" and "Alphabet"? Which of these should come first? Please, correct your question and remove any contradicting requirements.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

For your input sample (not actually an Atom feed), this stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="feed">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates>
                <xsl:sort select="update" order="descending"/>
                <xsl:sort select="title"/>
                <xsl:sort select="id" data-type="number"/>
            </xsl:apply-templates>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output:

```
<feed>
    <entry>
        <id>1</id>
        <updated>2011-01-18T16:55:54Z</updated>
        <title>title</title>
    </entry>
    <entry>
        <id>2</id>
        <updated>2011-01-18T16:55:54Z</updated>
        <title>title1</title>
    </entry>
    <entry>
        <id>3</id>
        <updated>2011-01-18T16:55:54Z</updated>
        <title>title1</title>
    </entry>
    <entry>
        <id>4</id>
        <updated>2011-01-18T16:55:54Z</updated>
        <title>title2</title>
    </entry>
</feed>
```

**Note**: This date time format can be ordered like string (default) as long as there is no different time zone.